# CFStringCompare and case insensitive sorting

Tags: ios, sorting, collation

Our goal is to write case insensitive collation for SQLite database. We did this for multiple platforms, but iOS seems to have consistent problems which (occasionally) manifest in corrupted DB indexes. After long experiments we concluded that the culprit is CFStringCompare() function, which violates theoretical rules.

Acc. to the theory the comparison function must be reflexive, symmtric and transitive.

What we did was to generate random strings and test whether CFStringCompare() fulfills above properties.

Here is a sample problem:
CFStringCompare with flags NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch yielded:

```
"Я7;1FC9" > "SДA`\"0l"
"SДA`\"0l" > "Я7;1FC9"
```

In other words A>B at the same time when B>A!

We tested more flag combinations:

- kCFCompareNonliteral showed similar problems
- kCFCompareLocalized prove to be the worst option (most problems)

Does anybody know about a safe way to realize case insensitive comparison under iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no reply, so I'll try to reply myself.

First of all, the other people observed similar problems, for example [this link](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/316843-inconsistent-behavior-of-nsstring-localizedcaseinsensitivecompare.html). Note that we also observed a lot of problems with German ß. I selected another example by chance.

This should be enough to say that CFStringCompare has buggy implementation and cannot be used for sorting.

On the other hand there is ICU library and they declare full compliance to UCA (for example [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation)), which in turn should obey all theoretical rules.

So my answer would be: **CFStringCompare is buggy, use ICU.**

(I hoped in another answer because of the huge size of the ICU library)